# iOS: How to subclass the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Why doesn't this work? I want to sublcass UINavigationBar so in xcode I click new file -> objective c class,
class: CustomNavBar 
subclass of: UINavigationBar

then in the storyboard under the navigation controller scene, I click on the Navigation Bar and set it's class to CustomNavBar.

I then go into my CustomNaVBar class and have tried to add a custom image background.

In the initWithFram method I have added this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSLog(@"Does it get here?"); //no
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customNavBarImage.png"];
        //  [self setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        NSLog(@"Does this get called?"); //no
    }
    return self;
}
```

I don't see any output on the console.

Instead I have done this to customize the UINavBar, but I feel like it isn't as correct as sublassing it. In my first view's viewDidLoad I added this line:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customNavBarImage.png"];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
}
```

Comment: Add that in `init` method or `layoutSubviews` method. It should work.

Comment: Well, I always just use viewDidLoad. Seems like subclassing is quite a bit of work for just settings the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Ryan Perry. In addition to his answer:

You should not put this code in `initWithFrame`, instead put your code in `awakeFromNib`

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customNavBarImage.png"];
    //  [self setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    NSLog(@"Does this get called?"); //YES!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for initWithFrame:

> If you use Interface Builder to design your interface, this method is **not** called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib file. Objects in a nib file are reconstituted and then initialized using their initWithCoder: method, which modifies the attributes of the view to match the attributes stored in the nib file. For detailed information about how views are loaded from a nib file, see Resource Programming Guide.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

This would be the reason that the method isn't geting called like you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using `initWithCoder:` method as that is the designated initializer when loading UI objects from the Storyboard. Hence, use this code:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    NSLog(@"Does it get here?"); // now it does! 
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
       // ...
        NSLog(@"Does this get called?"); // yep it does! 
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the UINavigation bar as follows:

```
@interface CustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@end

@implementation CustomNavigationBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{    
   //custom draw code
}

@end

//Begin of UINavigationBar background customization
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

//for iOS 5 
+ (Class)class {
    return NSClassFromString(@"CustomNavigationBar");
}

@end
```